# Spring Cloud Data Flow DLQ Configuration not working

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to configure DLQ in Spring Cloud Data Flow. Here is the Stream defination and how I am deploying it

```
  stream create --definition ":someTestTopic > custom-transform
     --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw | log --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw" --name ticktran


    stream deploy ticktran --properties
  "apps.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,apps.custom-transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.custom-transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=test-tran,app.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=test-tran,app.custom-transform.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.test-tran.consumer.enableDlq=true"
```

In custom-transform - processor code, I have mentioned

```
if(out.contains("ERROR")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error ");
        }
```

That means if message contains ERROR then RunTimeException and I want to capture those messages in DLQ. But it seems when I am running the code I am not getting any Kafka DL Queue with name test-tran.

Do i need to set more properties to enable DLQ or I need to change something in code for proper use of DLQ.

Custom Transform Code

TransformationServiceApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.hateoas.config.EnableEntityLinks;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEntityLinks
public class TransformationServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransformationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TransformationMessageEndPoint.java

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@MessageEndpoint
public class TransformationMessageEndpoint {

    private static final String NS = "http://openrisk.com/ingestion/";

    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(1);
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Object process(Message<?> message) {
        String out =  new String((byte[])message.getPayload());

        System.out.println("*****" + out);

        if(out.contains("ERROR")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error ");
        }

        return message;

    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server-local</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-modules-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Adding Module

```
app register --name custom-transform --type processor --uri maven://com.openrisk.openmargin:TransformationService:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Adding Stream

```
stream create --definition ":someTesstTopic > custom-transform | log " --name ticktran
```

Deploy Stream

```
stream deploy ticktran --properties "app.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.custom-transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.custom-transform.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq"
```

Comment: What version of SCDF are you using? The `module register` command is super old; at least 6-7 months old. We have moved away from these terms long back. Please try the latest [1.1 M1 release](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/).

Comment: With new version it is working. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please share your final findings and/or comments and perhaps also consider marking the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There were few issues with your stream definition.

- The deployment properties start with `app.<app-name>.`, but you've `apps.<app-name>.` in few places.
- The destinations are automatically created in SCDF, so having to override the defaults wouldn't be recommended. You can, however, do this when you're running standalone `spring-cloud-stream` applications.
- Instead of using custom destinations, you can enable DLQ by interacting with default channels directly - see example below.

> stream create --definition ":someTesssstTopic > transform | log " --name ticktran
>
> stream deploy ticktran --properties "app.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.transform.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq"

- The destination `test-tran` is not in the acceptable format when it comes to referring in the `app.transform.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.enableDlq` property.
- Lastly, the `error.<destination>.<group>` topic is only created when there's an error.

We will add few DSL samples to the reference guide via: [#885](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/885).

**EDIT:**
I updated the stream definition to reflect the right deployment property prefix.

Comment: Thanks Shabby. I tried above example and still DLQ not created. In the transformation code I am throwing RunTimeException and I am getting message getting processed 3 times because of exception, but after all processing, I am expecting message and exception to dump in DLQ which is not happening. Am i still missing some properties ?

Comment: Can we define error channel programmatically, i seen some example where errorchannel is defined in processor code. What is right way to do that and why there is need to defining error channel programmatically.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo(s) in the stream definition - I corrected it now. Could you please retry? Also, if you can share your custom processor code (_gh repo?_), we could try to replicate this behavior.

Comment: I have updated more details in originial post. Hope that will be helpful. What is name spring provide for kafka dlq ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Data flow version to [1.1 M1 release](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/) with the below mention command to create and deploy properties and it working now

```
stream create --definition ":someTesstTopic > transform | log " --name ticktran


stream deploy ticktran --properties "app.log.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.transform.spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw,app.transform.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq"
```

Thanks Sabby Anandan